# Which format to use for a shader resource view into depth-stencil buffer resource?

Tags: dxgi, directx-12, direct3d12

The depth-stencil buffer resource is defined as `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` format.

---

I would have assumed that to create a shader resource view (SRV) into that resource would require the view format to be described either as:

- `DXGI_FORMAT_R24_UNORM_X8_TYPELESS` where red channel accesses depth value
- `DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS` where red channel accesses depth and green channel stencil value

However, creating such SRV fails with the following error:

> D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateShaderResourceView: For the resource format D24_UNORM_S8_UINT, when making a D3D view, the format name for the view can't be R24_UNORM_X8_TYPELESS.  See documentation for the set of valid view format names for this resource format, determining which how the resource (or part of it) will appear to shader. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #28: CREATESHADERRESOURCEVIEW_INVALIDFORMAT]

Looking into [API doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn770406(v=vs.85).aspx) yielded me with the following piece of information:

> When viewing a resource, the resource-view description must specify a typed format, that is compatible with the resource format. So that means that **you can't create a resource-view description using any format with _TYPELESS in the name**. You can however view a typeless resource by specifying a typed format for the view.

---

I don't really understand *why a typeless format is not allowed* and *which format should I use instead*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the opposite, you create the resource with typeless components and you specialize the resource in a view with the final representation you need. Since you gave the resource stencil a uint representation already, you are stuck with it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense! I ended up defining the resource as `R24G8_TYPELESS`, DSV as `D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` and SRV as `R24_UNORM_X8_TYPELESS`.